# Ionic 3 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: android, node.js, ionic-framework, ionic3

When i run `ionic cordova run android --device` command for deploy my app i get following errors

> (node:6292) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Source path does not exist:
>   resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png
>
> (node:6292) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections
>   are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
>   will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: have you generated icon resources for android?

Comment: yes i generated icon resources for android... but still facing this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the following error,

`Error: Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png`

You need to check your config.xml, if I am not wrong.